# Do small icons have to pass at least 3:1 for contrast accessibility?

Tags: accessibility, icons, contrast, color-blindness

Can anyone clarify if icons (UI elements) 20x20 etc have to be 3:1 and is that a recommendation?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it must have at least a 3:1 contrast with adjacent colors.

The size of the icon is irrelevant with regards to WCAG unless you are working on AAA compliance, in which case, [WCAG 2.5.5 Target Size](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#target-size) might come into play which requires a clickable element be at least 44x44 pixels.

In WCAG 2.2 (still under development), there will be a AA recommendation for at least 24x24 pixel target size, [WCAG 2.5.8 Target Size (Minimum)](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG22/#target-size-minimum).

But getting back to contrast, [WCAG 1.4.11 Non-text Contrast](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#non-text-contrast) says that **non-text** (such as an icon) must have at least a 3:1 contrast to any *adjacent* colors (unless the clickable thing is inactive/disabled).

For example, the icons in the main menu at the top of ux.stackexchange look like this:

[image]

They're light gray icons (#D6D9DC) on an almost black background (#232629).  The contrast is 10.7:1 so significantly passes.

But if the icons were darker, such as ##6A6D70, the contrast would be 2.9:1, which just barely fails (although it's pretty difficult to see them so it would seem like it should be a more significant failure than just 0.1 away from passing).

[image]

If the '?' in the middle icon were a different color, such as lightblue, then the lightblue against the (original) lighter gray icon background would need to be at least 3:1.

[image]

This would fail with a 2.5:1 contrast.

Comment: Very well articulated @slugolicious

Comment: I see so even if the icon isn't clickable more for show. Example:
(icon location pin) then address text, (icon phone) phone number. Even though these aren't clickable same rule applies 3:1 I assume. Thank you

Comment: @Keano, you just provided more information than what you originally asked. I was assuming your icons were interactive elements.  WCAG 1.4.11 deals with two types of elements: interactive and graphical. The latter doesn't necessarily have to be a graph or chart - just a "graphical" element - which it sounds like your "location pin" is.  So, yes, the 3:1 minimum contrast does apply to your situation.